# Options to grow a Docker host into an orchestrated [nano]cluster

Tags: kubernetes, fedora, docker-swarm

I'm seeking a little advice,

I have a **Fedora Server 32 VM** as a Docker (not Podman) host. I think I may have outgrown it so basically either I add more resources to the VM or I add another VM and cluster them.

Just throwing more resources at it doesn't feel like a good idea 'cause then I'd end up with a huge single point of failure than if I were to split the load, regardless of the physical host--or that's what I believe, please correct me if I'm wrong.

I'll need some orchestration obviously, I use Portainer but *use* is more like a shortcut to see status, I prefer the CLI and only use (and learn) options as I need them. Portainer is more like a supervision thing, not an orchestrator so I was thinking about Swarm for that as Kubernetes is too complex and AFAIK two hosts are too little for even the smallest deployment.

***Or are they?*** What's the minimum host count where Kubernetes starts being useful and not only a dev environment like minikube/minishift? I know that K8s needs a master node, so that'd be at least 3, right?

Or *alternatively* can two or more minikube/minishift *all-in-one*-type deployments (which are **much** easier to deploy) be clustered?

I'm open to any suggestion. Storage for the containers is on NFS files shares, I use Cockpit to do basic config quickly and always the same and I keep a file of all the containers deployed so I can recreate it again exactly the same if anything were to happen or if, *say,* I'd switch to an Ubuntu Server host. So really ANY suggestion is welcome. I prefer Fedora or RHEL but I'm not tied to them.

If I need to sit down and learn K8s for good, then I'll guess I'll have to, TBH I find all of the complexity hard to justify because *while Kubernetes might be self-healing* when running, if one of the underlying, **uniquely**-set-up components fails, can it heal that?

Comment: Pretty much all of us are going to end up learning Kubernetes sooner or later, I suspect. Try kubespray for a quick and easy deployment.

Comment: Can AIOs be clustered though, even if they are slightly less efficient? I actually got the Kubernetes License for VMware only to learn that to deploy, parts of the datancntr struct. are referenced=if I changed the name of a cluster/datastore/whatever things would break. That can't possibly be a good mature solution. I'm just getting home and gonna try your suggestion. …man! Am I gonna eat my own words laters when we switch to containers from VM arrives.

Comment: Any results ? Did you try Kubespray ?